# Ultimate Member WordPress plugin : change text "edit profile" to "edit xyz" in profile form/tab

Tags: wordpress, web, membership

I'm using **Ultimate Member** WordPress plugin. I want to change text "Edit Profile" to "Edit xyz". But, I can't find "Edit Profile" in the plugin editor. Can any one tell me where do I change the text? Or Is there any other way?

[image]

Comment: please share plugin url

Answer (score 0):

1. open the following file um-actions-profile.php
   your-wordpress/wp-content/plugins/ultimate-member/includes/core
2. Find for 'Edit Profile'
3. Replace it with whatever you want make sure this can be changed on plugin update.
4. In my code it was line number. 1077
5. you can also use following code so that if the plugin updates the changes will remain same , add this code in active themes functions.php

   ```
   add_filter( 'um_myprofile_edit_menu_items', 'my_profile_edit_menu_items', 20, 1 );function my_profile_edit_menu_items( $items ) {$items = array(
   'editprofile' => '<a href="' . um_edit_profile_url() . '" class="real_url">' . __( 'Edit xyz', 'ultimate-member' ) . '</a>',
   'myaccount'   => '<a href="' . um_get_core_page( 'account' ) . '" class="real_url">' . __( 'My Account', 'ultimate-member' ) . '</a>','logout'      => '<a href="' . um_get_core_page( 'logout' ) . '" class="real_url">' . __( 'Logout', 'ultimate-member' ) . '</a>',
   'cancel'      => '<a href="#" class="um-dropdown-hide">' . __( 'Cancel', 'ultimate-member' ) . '</a>',);return $items;}
   ```